# Multiline input form field using Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

```
<form class="span6">
  <h2>Get In Touch</h2><br>
  <input class="span6" type="text" placeholder="Your first name" required>
  <input class="span6" type="text" placeholder="Your last name" required>
  <input class="span6" type="email" placeholder="Your email" required>
  <input class="span6" type="text" placeholder="Your phone number">
  <input class="span6" type="text" rows="3" placeholder="What's up?" required><br>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  <button type="clear" class="btn">Clear</button>
</form><!--/.span6-->
```

Here's my form I'm using in Bootstrap.  I'm trying to make my last input field span 6 columns across and 3 rows down, but it's only showing as 6 columns across and 1 row down.  Any ideas on how to make my input box larger?  Thanks.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are using type="text" instead of textarea. What you want is:

```
<textarea class="span6" rows="3" placeholder="What's up?" required></textarea>
```

To clarify, a type="text" will always be one row, where-as a textarea can be multiple.

Comment: According to [bootstrap's docs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#textual-<input>s-only) this might not be the best idea: "Avoid using `<textarea>` elements here as their `row`s attribute will not be respected in some cases."

Comment: That link you provide says to avoid textarea elements within input-group's, which this is not

Comment: Touché, @nick-mithinson. I think I'll leave my comment in, because people might land on this question while using `input-group`s. Thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 45):

The answer by Nick Mitchinson is for Bootstrap version 2.

If you are using Bootstrap version 3, then forms have changed a bit. For bootstrap 3, use the following instead:

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" placeholder="What's up?" required></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Where, col-md-6 will target medium sized devices. You can add col-xs-6 etc to target smaller devices.